# Able to take controls in parent window even after launch of another dialog using DoModal

Tags: visual-c++

I have an application which is created using MFC and I have created a MFC dll on click of a button the exe will call the dll which in turn will launch a dll using dialogClass.DoModal().
My Problem is even after this dialog I am able to access my parent application. which I should 
not be able to access. Is there any setting for this . Can somebody help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have created a modal-less dialog. If you create the same dialog as a modal pop-up dialog, then you should get the behaviour you have described.

This link should give you the information you are looking for: [Using Dialog boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644996%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Other links that might be useful are:

1. [Dialog box styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729172(v=VS.85).aspx)
2. [Window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600(v=VS.85).aspx)